# Control a motor with a button

Tags: arduino-uno, motor, button

Code:

```
int motorPin = 9;  // the pin the motor is connected to

void setup()
{
 pinMode(motorPin, OUTPUT); 
}

void loop()                     
{
 motorOnThenOff(); //motorAcceleration
}

void motorOnThenOff(){
  int onTime = 2500;  //the number of milliseconds for the motor to turn on for
  int offTime = 1000; //the number of milliseconds for the motor to turn off for

  digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH); // turns the motor On
  delay(onTime);                // waits for onTime milliseconds
  digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW);  // turns the motor Off
  delay(offTime);               // waits for offTime milliseconds
}

void motorOnThenOffWithSpeed(){

  int onSpeed = 200;  // a number between 0 (stopped) and 255 (full speed) 
  int onTime = 2500;  //the number of milliseconds for the motor to turn on for

  int offSpeed = 50;  // a number between 0 (stopped) and 255 (full speed) 
  int offTime = 1000; //the number of milliseconds for the motor to turn off for

  analogWrite(motorPin, onSpeed);   // turns the motor On
  delay(onTime);                    // waits for onTime milliseconds
  analogWrite(motorPin, offSpeed);  // turns the motor Off
  delay(offTime);                   // waits for offTime milliseconds
}

void motorAcceleration(){
  int delayTime = 50; //milliseconds between each speed step

  //Accelerates the motor
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){ //goes through each speed from 0 to 255
    analogWrite(motorPin, i);   //sets the new speed
    delay(delayTime);           // waits for delayTime milliseconds
  }

  //Decelerates the motor
  for(int i = 255; i >= 0; i--){ //goes through each speed from 255 to 0
    analogWrite(motorPin, i);   //sets the new speed
    delay(delayTime);           // waits for delayTime milliseconds
  }
}
```

This code spins the motor. In the circuit, I have a button which I want to toggle the spinning of the motor.

This is the circuit:

https://circuits.io/circuits/4267039-spin-motor-spin/edit

How would I make it so that the button toggles the spinning of the motor? like a fan and its switch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this variable at the top of your program:

```
const int buttonPin = XX;   // the pin for the button
bool bState = false;
```

in the setup() function:

```
pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
// in case INPUT_PULLUP is not defined, comment the above line and uncomment below
//pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
//digitalWrite (buttonPin, HIGH);  // enable internal pull-up
```

in the loop() function, change your code with this:

```
update_bState();

if (bState) { digitalWrite(motorPin, HIGH); }
else        { digitalWrite(motorPin, LOW); }
```

then, at the end of your program, add the getButton function:

```
void update_bState(void)
{
    static bool buttonDone = false;
    static uint16_t timeButton;

    if (!digitalRead(buttonPin))
    {
        if ((!buttonDone) && ((uint16_t) (millis() - timeButton) > 100))
        { // Do once when button is pressed for at least 100ms (debounce)
            bState ^= true;     // Toggle button state
            buttonDone = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        buttonDone = false;
        timeButton = millis();
    }
}
```

Now that all the work is done, you should add acceleration when launching and deceleration when launching and stopping :D

By the way, I did not tested any code, so there may be some typo errors...

Comment: Yes I do, first line I tell to add in the loop

Comment: I beg your pardon, so you do

Comment: No problem. I checked, I could have forgotten something.

Comment: you have some issues in the circuit too, you need to put pull up or pull down resistors with push button in order to stop floating values.

Comment: @Muhammad Did you notice that the button is initialized as INPUT_PULLUP? This enables internal microcontroller pull-up resistor for the pin, thus avoiding the use of external pull for the button.

Comment: I also used that KEYWORD twice but it didn't work for me that's why I ask about that.

Comment: @Muhammad depending your board definitions or arduino version, INPUT_PULLUP may not be defined. In this case, pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT); digitalWrite(buttonPin, HIGH); should work. Writing a 1 to an input declared pin turns the internal pull-up on.

Comment: Thanks for sharing such information and for enhancing my knowledge.